# Rails - Skip data_migrations in specific environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-migration

I am writing a data_migration for which I am using data-migrate gem. I have a situation where I should skip one specific data_migration in Production environment alone. I can do it like this

```
class BackfillNonStatutoryResultsWithAssessmentPeriod < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def up 
    unless RAILS_ENV == "production"
     # Do something
    end
  end
end

 def down
   raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

What is the best and efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Btw, I'm thinking of integrating this library into my project. I'd like to know if it's worth it. Does this library work well on your project? Are you satisfied with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code looks fine, but I would improve it a little bit

```rb
class BackfillNonStatutoryResultsWithAssessmentPeriod < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def up
    return if Rails.env.production?
    # Do something
  end

  def down
   raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Never used the gem before, but [the README](https://github.com/ilyakatz/data-migrate#why-should-i-use-this) seems to be clear that this gem's whole purpose is to enable you to have a separate rake task for migrating with data vs just schema:

> For setting tasks that don't require any intermediate AR activity, like dev and test, you stick with `db:migrate`. For production and QA, you change their scripts to `db:migrate:with_data`.

If you're having an issue with that then it's not clear from your question.